# Can a person be described as 'oriented'?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

She knows her way in life.
She knows what's good for her and what is bad.
In short - she is **oriented**.
Is this a possible and correct use of the word "oriented"?

Thanks

Comment: 'Balanced' and 'grounded' have achieved 'detached' (standalone) metaphor status. _She's grounded._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **disoriented** (usually **disorientated** in the UK) certainly has a well-known metaphorical usage.

> *disoriented* [adjective] [US] [also mainly UK *disorientated*)
>
> - confused and not knowing where to go or what to do

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disoriented)]

> *disoriented*
>
> - having lost one's sense of time, place, or identity

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disoriented)]

......................

However, the antonym (fully grounded and knowing where you're going [in life]) is not *oriented* but **well-oriented**.

An example from [Linked in](https://www.linkedin.com/in/arlene-alacar-34abb0122):

> Arlene is a very well oriented person. She keeps a positive attitude
> and always exceeds her achievement. Arlene stays dedicated to her work
> and always stay ahead of her work. I can rely on her for advice and
> knowing what to expect in the work field because she already is
> employed in the medical field.

And an example from a CV on [fiverr.com](https://www.fiverr.com/hmirfan121/assist-you-in-general-organic-chemistry-and-biology-by-making-assignments):

> I'm an innovative, highly motivated, organized, and well-oriented
> person.

Comment: Neither of the examples proposed for *well-orientated* uses a form with that redundant *-ta-* syllable (as in *preventative* for *preventive);* and only one hyphenates the *well.*

Comment: Oops, slipping into English English. Well-orientated is the form usually (though it's not that common a usage) encountered in the UK, and the hyphen is usual, at least when the compound adjective is used prenominally.

Comment: I cannot find dictionary warrant for OP's proposed usage, but I wonder if it might pass and be understood in a kind of semi-jocose way--like *couth, kempt,* and *gruntled,* jocose but intelligible coinages formed by removing negative prefixes from words already in common use. OP's proposed *oriented* could conceivably stand in that relation to *disoriented.* But *oriented* is otherwise too common a word for that.